# Need to get specific SW information from Android phone in app

Tags: android

I am working on an app that will access different items in the phone status screen for work. I need to be able to get specific software information from the phone to populate in the app. For example: in the droid x, the system version shows as 4.5.605.MB810.Verizon.en.us . This is the software info I need to auto populate. I have tried all of the Build options from the android developer site and I have even tried the SYSTEM_VERSION string from telephony, but they all provide information other than what I need. Can anyone tell me how to reference this software information please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `android.os.Build`.  Here are the details:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html

And for OS version specifics, use the nested class `Build.VERSION` detailed here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but I tried CODENAME, INCREMENTAL, and RELEASE and none of them give me the info.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Settings app code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) for where it gets its information.